# Javascript returns 0 height. Works with setTimeout 0

Tags: javascript, reflow

I'm having a weird problem while calculating the height of an element.
It will be at height 0 in the beginning, animating it to its original height.
If I remove the setTimeout, I always get 0 as the height (even when using plain javascript).

```js
var $element = $(element);
$element.addClass("accessibleHidden"); //Position absolute off the screen
//Wait for the element to reflow, or you'll get zero-height
setTimeout(function() {
    var height = $element.height();
    $element.removeClass("accessibleHidden").addClass("collapsed").transit({ height: height }, 2000, "easeOutBack");
}, 0);
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: The way around it *is* `setTimeout`.

Comment: But shouldn't height() do an actual reflow?

Comment: I don't think so, but reading `offsetHeight` does. Maybe that's your answer.